# How can I screen scrape with Perl?

Tags: perl, screen-scraping

I need to display some values that are stored in a website, for that I need to scrape the website and fetch the content from the table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

If you are familiar with jQuery you might want to check out [pQuery](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/pQuery-0.07/lib/pQuery.pm), which makes this very easy:

```
## print every <h2> tag in page
use pQuery;

pQuery("http://google.com/search?q=pquery")
    ->find("h2")
    ->each(sub {
        my $i = shift;
        print $i + 1, ") ", pQuery($_)->text, "\n";
    });
```

There's also [HTML::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-DOM/).

Whatever you do, though, don't use regular expressions for this.

Answer (score 4):

I have used [HTML Table Extract](http://search.cpan.org/~msisk/HTML-TableExtract-2.10/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm) in the past.
I personally find it a bit clumsy to use, but maybe I did not understand the object model well.
I usually use this part of the manual to examine the data:

```
 use HTML::TableExtract;
 $te = HTML::TableExtract->new();
 $te->parse($html_string);

     # Examine all matching tables
     foreach $ts ($te->tables) {
       print "Table (", join(',', $ts->coords), "):\n";
       foreach $row ($ts->rows) {
          print join(',', @$row), "\n";
       }
     }`
```

Comment: HTML::TableExtract is quite magical. One great feature is being able to select tables by specifying the contents of header cells and being able to keep only the columns you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

Although I've generally done this with [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.825/lib/LWP.pm)/[LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.825/lib/LWP/Simple.pm), the current 'preferred' module for any sort of webpage scraping in Perl is [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.54/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm).

Comment: David: Can you expand on this. I always thought WWW::Mechanize was more for automated testing. What puts it a cut above?

Comment: WWW::Mechanize is for any sort of interaction with a website. It was never targeted just at automated testing.

Comment: However, Test::WWW::Mechanize *is* targeted just at automated testing.  It is a wrapper around WWW::Mechanize.

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with XPath, you can also use [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath). And if you're not... well you should be ;--)

Answer (score 2):

For similar Stackoverflow questions have a look at....

- [How can I extract URLs from a web page in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254345/how-can-i-extract-urls-from-a-web-page-in-perl)
- [How can I extract XML of a website and save in a file using Perl’s LWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221091/how-can-i-extract-xml-of-a-website-and-save-in-a-file-using-perls-lwp)

I do like using [pQuery](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/pQuery/) for things like this however [Web::Scraper](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Web-Scraper/) does look interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use this simple perl module WEB::Scraper, this is simple to understand and make life easy for me. follow this example for more information.

http://teusje.wordpress.com/2010/05/02/web-scraping-with-perl/

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to drag up a dead thread but anyone googling across this thread should also checkout [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-0.010/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod) - 'For scripting web sites that have scripts'

happy remote data aggregating ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the magical [Web::Scraper](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Web-Scraper/), it's **THE** tool for web scraping.

Answer (score 0):

I use [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.825/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) for most of my screen scraping needs. You can also Couple that with [HTTP::Cookies](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.825/lib/HTTP/Cookies.pm) if you need Cookies support.

Here's a simple example on how to get source.

```
use LWP;
use HTTP::Cookies;
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new;
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$browser->cookie_jar($cookie_jar);

$resp = $browser->get("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
if($resp->is_success) {
   # Play with your source here
   $source = $resp->content;
   $source =~ s/^.*<table>/<table>/i; # this is just an example 
   print $source;                     # not a solution to your problem.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this little example of web scraping with perl:
[link text](http://teusje.wordpress.com/2010/05/02/web-scraping-with-perl/)